# dynamic sql generation error occured when trying to update database

Tags: sql, vb.net, dynamic-sql

I followed your code and I have put it a msgbox to confirm and yes its returns the right row number. However an error occurred here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da) 'command builder to update the database

    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(0) = TextBox1.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(1) = TextBox2.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(2) = TextBox3.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(3) = TextBox4.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(4) = TextBox5.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(5) = TextBox6.Text 'update dataset
    ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(marker).Item(6) = TextBox7.Text 'update dataset



    da.Update(ds, "inventory_table") 'this is where the updating of database takes place
    MsgBox("Data updated")
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DoubleClick
    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
    TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
    TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
    TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value
    TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
    TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value


    marker = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index


    MsgBox(marker)

End Sub
```

The error says:

> dynamic sql generation for the updatecommand is not supporyed against
> a selectcommand that does not return any key column information

and the line `da.update(ds, "inventory_table")` is highlighted.

Comment: @PLASMAchicken You could have improved the grammar in the question and the title while you were removing the "please" ;)

Answer (score -1):

In the double click event set a global variable:

```
_rowIndex = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
```

Then

```
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(1) = TextBox1.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(2) = TextBox2.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(3) = TextBox3.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(4) = TextBox4.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(5) = TextBox5.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(6) = TextBox6.Text 
ds.Tables("inventory_table").Rows(_rowIndex).Item(7) = TextBox7.Text
```

Comment: Is the underscore before the variable required?

Comment: No, it's a common way of identifying a global variable.